# What is the ideal http response code to render when resource isn't available?

Tags: http, web, server

Let's say that we are building a 'forgot password' page where a user is expected to enter its email id. What if email id doesn't match any record in our database? Should we still respond with 200?

Comment: actually I am not getting you perfectly, what's your requirement? if you want to respond with 200 then do that way else we can show some custom message too. it is depend on the ones requirement.

Comment: I won't tell them anything, if you do someone can guess email addresses and when he doesn't get the error response he has one part of the two part key, the other being the password

Answer (score 0):

So after exploring more on this, I feel that I should still respond with 200 since there is nothing wrong with the request and request parameters. Its still a valid request.

It may also be worth to note that it makes complete sense to respond with 401 when a user is trying to access resource that doesn't belong to it.

This ('password reset' or 'check username availability') isn't a 401 scenario. 200 seems good.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah it will be still response **200 OK**.

For security reasons is better don't do information email doesn't exists in database. It's better return only information incorrect credentials. Attacker haven't information if account with email exists or not.

Different situation will be in case of API. in this case will be good return response **401 Unauthorized** with message "Incorect credentials" for better catch in client application.